# Removing substring from string before calling strtok in C

Tags: c, strtok, string-parsing, pointer-arithmetic

I have a variable that I would like to split into an array of paths:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Where the result of the above string would be the following:

```
[0] -> /bin
[1] -> /usr/bin
[2] -> /usr/local/bin
```

If I just call `strtok` on the string with the delimiter `:` I get the results:

```
[0] -> PATH=/bin
[1] -> /usr/bin
[2] -> /usr/local/bin
```

But then I still have `PATH=` as a substring at the first index of the array. I need to find a way to remove `PATH=` from the string before I call `strtok`.

Rather than having to reallocate a new array of char without the `PATH=` substring, I thought I could increment the char pointer to point to the first character after `PATH=`.

```
char prefix[] = "PATH=";

if (strstr(str, prefix)) {
    str += strlen(prefix);
}
```

So now the pointer str points to the first / after `PATH=`.

Before `str += strlen(prefix)`:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
↑
```

After `str += strlen(prefix)`:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
     ↑
```

And I get the following array of paths from `strtok`.

```
[0] -> /bin
[1] -> /usr/bin
[2] -> /usr/local/bin
```

Would this be considered bad practice in C? Are there any side effects from doing so? Should I take another approach: I.e. allocate a new buffer and copy the value of str into the new buffer without `PATH=`.

Comment: You can use `char* temp = strchr(str, '=')` to get to the '=' position and then `str = temp+1`.This way you don't need to store "PATH=" in some char array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `strtok()` with `"="` as the delimiter the first time, then do the calls with `":"` (and NULL) thereafter.  You can change the delimiters on each call to `strtok()` if you have a need to do so.

Of course, this assumes you don't mind `strtok()` butchering your string in the first place.  Make sure you're working on a copy of your PATH variable.

What you propose also works fine.  The only gotcha I see is if `str` is the only pointer to the start of dynamically allocated space, you can no long free the space (memory leak).  You need to decide whether that's a problem — and if it is, the solution is easy: keep a copy of the pointer that needs to be freed so you can free it.

Also note that PATH is really weird:

```
PATH=:/usr/bin::/bin:
```

has three 'implicit' `.` elements in it: before the first `:`, between the middle two, and after the last one.  Clearly, you would not normally have all three at once, but you need to know the rules of the game.